# How many classes and packages do we have in java 6?

Tags: java

I would like to know the number of built in classes and packages that are available with Java 6.

Please provide me the url from where this information is available.

Thanks

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you looking for this information?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

3793 after a line count of http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/allclasses-frame.html

(less one for the heading)

EDIT: 203 packages in http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/overview-frame.html

Comment: I guess you could also add the system classes for the primitives 'int' 'char' etc, but that is just being really picky

Answer (score 2):

I have counted it : 203 packages and 3792 classes

Comment: Use the Java 6 API webpage. Select all the text in the 2 frames, paste each into `wc -l` or an editor with line numbers, you get 3793 classes, 203 packages. So either you should explain why I'm wrong by 1 count or you should edit your answer and make it right.